# Как перевести локальные координаты в глобальные в Blender

Tags: unity3d, 3d, blender

У меня есть моделька икосферы.
Каждый шестиугольник у нее как отдельный объект (мне так надо).
Только вот задача рассчитывать что то по их координатам, а в юнити у каждого 6-угольника
координаты оказались (0, 0, 0).

Всему виной разница в локальных и глобальных координатах...
На данный момент они все смещены по локальным координатам в блендере, а глобальные по нулям
Мне же нужно перевести все лок. координаты в глобальные, желательно можно все сразу,
но если нельзя то я и по одному помучаюсь, только как то бы ускорить этот процесс, и не вводить каждую координату отдельно

[image: Сфера]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо origin  у них в центре координат. Попробуй переместить его в "центр геометрии"

[https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14294/how-to-recenter-an-objects-origin#:~:text=Press%20Shift%20%2B%20Ctrl%20%2B%20Alt%20%2B,and%20select%20Origin%20to%20Geometry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14294/how-to-recenter-an-objects-origin#:%7E:text=Press%20Shift%20%2B%20Ctrl%20%2B%20Alt%20%2B,and%20select%20Origin%20to%20Geometry).

> Press Shift + Ctrl + Alt + C (perhaps the longest shortcut in Blender)
> and select Origin to Geometry.

И кстати они вложены в общего родителя? Если не сработает, то попробуй вложить.

Comment: Да, ответ очень полезен) В новом блендере это Выделить -> Объект -> Задать центральную точку
Даже работает для всех сразу